# Libarchive on Linux not installed properly (for Python)

Tags: python, libarchive

I installed libarchive on my Ubuntu box using `apt install libarchive-dev` and then used pip to install libarchive for Python `pip3 install libarchive`.

My issue now is that the installation seems be incorrect as libarchive does not provide any function at all as indicated by the following output:

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Aug 20 2019, 17:04:43) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libarchive
>>> dir(libarchive)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__']
```

and the library itself

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4M Feb  6  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Feb  6  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so -> libarchive.so.13.3.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Feb  6  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13 -> libarchive.so.13.3.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 722K Feb  6  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13.3.3
```

I tried this both on Ubuntu 19.04 and 18.04 and got the same result each time. I figure I must be missing something obvious but I can't find it for the life of me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: All of the libarchive examples I see use something like `import libarchive.public` - apparently the top-level module doesn't contain anything but submodules.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for that. This is indeed the solution. The legacy code I had did not use this, hence I never tried that. If you want to post your reply as answer I'd gladly mark it as solution. Cheers

Comment: There's a reason for the confusion, as there are 2 different versions of libarchive for python, the one I used which can be installed with pip as libarchive and the other as libarchive-c